# Android create background service

Tags: java, android

How to create a service that will run even when the application is closed. Ways that I found in Google do not work for my Le Eco Android 6.0.1

Comment: What did you found? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried services, a reviver, a ready-made firebot-based pushbot library, it works for my phone, but doesn’t work for Meizu, because Google services are not pre-installed there. And the ways with services work on a Meizu, but do not work on Lee Eco, the service just dies on Lee Eco.

Comment: There is no way to assure the OS will never kill a Service.  Android isn't designed that way.    A better approach is to describe what you're trying to do, and maybe we can help you architect a way to do it.

Comment: In the MainActivity, I run my service NotificationListener. `Intent intent= new Intent(this, NotificationListener.getClass());
            startService(intent);`

Comment: In the Notification create new Handler which, every 10 seconds, sends a post request to the server and receives a response, and in case there is an answer, displays notifications

Comment: Perhaps there is another way to make real-time notifications?

Comment: Ok, service work on Meizu. But on Le Eco was killed

Comment: Why do you need to run a request every 10s?  That's going to completely kill your battery.  In fact its exactly why Google doesn't let you do this.

Comment: I set 60 seconds, the situation has not changed.